# Pluggable Function wp_new_user_notification exists too early

Tags: pluggable

I have recently updated from 4.1 to 4.4 directly and I can't override `wp_new_user_notification` anymore.

Obviously the function should not exist when the plugins are loaded. I wrote a mu-plugin with the following:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', function() {
    $reflFunc = new ReflectionFunction('wp_new_user_notification');
    error_log(date('H:i:s', strtotime('now')) . ":\n" . print_r(['action' => current_filter(), 'exists' => function_exists('wp_new_user_notification'), 'defined' => $reflFunc->getFileName() . ':' . $reflFunc->getStartLine()], true) . "\n", 3, trailingslashit(WP_CONTENT_DIR) . 'debug.log');
});
```

and the output always is:

```
11:09:46:
Array
(
    [action] => plugins_loaded
    [exists] => 1
    [defined] => /var/www/wordpress/web/wp-includes/pluggable.php:1742
)
```

Any ideas on what might be happening here?

---

For the sake of completeness. In my plugin file I have:

```
// this overrides the default welcome email
if (!function_exists('wp_new_user_notification')){ 
    function wp_new_user_notification($user_id, $deprecated, $notify) {
        $welcome = new \PiEmail\WelcomeEmail();
        $welcome->constructWelcome($user_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Plugins are loaded before `pluggable.php`, but the `plugins_loaded` action fires after `pluggable.php` is loaded. You can see this in [the source of `wp-settings.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-settings.php#L252) where this happens.

Comment: I am fully aware of that. The `['exists']` element might be a bit misleading as I know that the function is defined at that point.

Comment: If I put `if(!function_exists('wp_new_user_notification')){ die('overridden'); }` in a plugin in a new 4.4.1 install, I see the `overridden` message.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I don't see that. The function seems to be defined before the plugins' function is registered...

Comment: I'd guess you've got some other code in a theme or plugin that appears to be doing something wrong then.

Comment: Possibly something is wrong. But the question is what and where. I don't get any php errors (or warnings or strict warnings for that matter). Maybe anyone else has seen this fail silently.

Comment: it's hard to guess without knowing specifics of your setup. have you tried disabling all plugins and switching to a default theme? and you're trying to override it directly within your plugin file, not hooked to any action?